# Why i cant run exec in php when run script with machine name?

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec

Helle coders,
I have a PHP script that contains the following three lines. my server is Ubuntu and I run this code over the network with server IP or server hostname. when I run this script with server IP, there is no problem. but when i try to run this code with server host name, the code running but the exec wont execute. Does anybody have any idea? how I can solve this problem?

```
<?php
   $total_sys_memory = array();
   exec("awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", $total_sys_memory);
   print_r($total_sys_memory);
?>
```

I think the issue may be with the privilege of call exec with the server hostname.

when with the browser in client system open this script with the address below :

```
http://192.168.1.101/armiti/login/script.php
```

exec run. but when I open this script with the address below :

```
http://server/armiti/login/script.php
```

exec won't run. why?

Comment: how are you calling this cli script?

Comment: Mostly sounds like a vhost misconfiguration. Albeit first investigate the invocation: [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

Comment: From the manual:     Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable.

Perhaps the safe_mode is set on the target server